How to click an element without navigating away from the page
I would like to ask whether it is there a way for you to select an element without going to be navigate away,
I am new to coding , I trying to automate the unfollowing button. in instagram
unfolllow
let say I wanted to unfollow all by dbclick the "following" , can I just run my code on homepage URL?
https://www.instagram.com/_chaeboll/ -- home page url
https://www.instagram.com/_chaeboll/following/ -- after clicking following
const unfollow = document.querySelectorAll("following")

unfollow.forEach(() => { runing the code to click the button})


as the element isnt in home page , it will returned undefined, but i hope there is away when something happen in background which navigate away to the following URL and execute the code.

I know u can use the deobfuscate/debuggger to find the function which are called to do the action, but it is to advance for me to find the function
Im building it as extension in content.js
if there is isnt , is there any resources that teaches the process of automating things for me to learn more about finding the way to deobfuscate

You could automate the navigation to the "/following/" page, and once you're on that page, you can select and click the "following" buttons.
// Check if you're on the homepage
if (window.location.href === "https://www.instagram.com/_chaeboll/") {
    // Navigate to the following page
    window.location.href = "https://www.instagram.com/_chaeboll/following/";
}

// Check if you're on the following page
if (window.location.href === "https://www.instagram.com/_chaeboll/following/") {
    // Once on the following page, select all "following" buttons and click them
    const unfollowButtons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

    unfollowButtons.forEach(button => {
        if (button.textContent.includes("Following")) {
            button.click();
            // Add additional logic to handle confirmation popups if needed
        }
    });
}


Aaa thanks , by the way i found out the term for it in Puppeteer , it  is called headless, thanks for the assistant
